# I want to show percentage on Google Pie Chart

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I want to show percentage on my jquery 3D google chart (please see attached image).
Please advise how I can achieve it.

I have used the below code to implement the jQuery google chart. 
I am getting the 3D chart but wanted to display percentage on each duadrant google chart.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190726?hl=en

```
$('#pieChart').gchart({
    type : 'p3',
    series : data,
    legend : 'top',
    dataLabels : [ 'HR', 'SRM', 'MM', 'SD' ],
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    // dataColors : [ 'red', 'lime', 'blue', 'green' ],
    extension : {
        chdl : 'HR|SRM|MM|SD',
        chco : 'FF0000|00FF00|0000FF|BB0000',
        chs : '450x100'
    }
});



/**
 * 
 */

$(function() {

var data = [ $.gchart.series('2012', [ 16.1, 33.9, 25.4, 16.4 ]),
        $.gchart.series('2013', [ 11.7, 34.1, 25.1, 22.1 ]) ];

var data1 = [ $.gchart.series('2012', [ 50.0, 25.4, 16.4 ]),
        $.gchart.series('2013', [ 45.8, 25.1, 22.1 ]) ];

$('#pieChart').gchart({
    type : 'p3',
    series : data,
    legend : 'top',
    dataLabels : [ 'HR', 'SRM', 'MM', 'SD' ],
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    // dataColors : [ 'red', 'lime', 'blue', 'green' ],
    extension : {
        chdl : 'HR|SRM|MM|SD',
        chco : 'FF0000|00FF00|0000FF|BB0000',
        chs : '450x100'
    }
});

$('input[name=pieType],#pieColours,#pieAngle').change(function() {
    /*
     * data[0].color = ($('#pieAngle').val() == 1 ? [ 'red', 'lime', 'blue',
     * 'green' ] : null);
     * 
     * data[1].color = ($('#pieAngle').val() == 2 ? [ 'ff8888', '88ff88',
     * '8888ff' ] : null);
     */
    $('#removeChart').toggle(function() {
        $(this).text('Re-attach');
        $('#defaultChart').gchart('destroy');
    }, function() {
        $(this).text('Remove');
        $('#defaultChart').gchart();
    });


    if (($('#pieAngle').val() == 1)) {
        //alert($('#pieAngle').val());
        $('#pieChart').gchart('option', {
            type : 'p3',

            series : data1,

            extension : {
                chdl : 'HR|SRM|MM',
                chco : '0000FF',
                chs : '450x100'
            }
        });
    } else if (($('#pieAngle').val() == 2)) {
        //alert($('#pieAngle').val());

        $('#pieChart').gchart('option', {
            type : 'p3',

            series : data,

            /*
             * pieOrientation : $('#pieAngle') .val(),
             */

            extension : {
                chdl : 'HR|SRM|MM|SD',
                chco : 'FF0000|00FF00|0000FF|BB0000',
                chs : '450x100'
            }
        });
    } else if (($('#pieAngle').val() == 3)) {
        //alert($('#pieAngle').val());

        $('#pieChart').gchart('option', {

            type : 'p3',

            series : data1,

            extension : {
                chdl : 'HR|SRM|MM',
                chco : 'ff8888 | 88ff88 | 8888ff| BB0000',
                chs : '450x100'
            }
        });
    } else if (($('#pieAngle').val() == 10)) {
        //alert($('#pieAngle').val());

        $('#pieChart').gchart('option', {
            type : 'p3',

            series : data,

            extension : {
                chdl : 'HR|SRM|MM|SD',
                chco : 'FF0000|00FF00|0000FF|BB0000',
                chs : '450x100'
            }
        });
    } 
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the [Google Charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options) set **pieSliceText** to *percentage*.

Answer (score 0):

Given the options you are passing to the `gchart` plugin, I believe that the plugin uses the deprecated Image Chart API, and not the newer Interactive Chart API.  I suggest either using the newer API or a different charting API, as the Image Chart API is scheduled to go offline April 20, 2015.

That said, the option you need to use to enable percent labels on the pie slices is the `chl` option.  This takes a pipe-delimited string of labels to apply to the pie slices, in order, eg:

```
chl: '10%|25%|35%|15%|10%|5%'
```

This is *only* applicable for the Image Chart API.  The Interactive Chart API uses the `pieSliceText` option as pointed out in Magnus Burton's answer.

Comment: Actually i had to generate chart using jQuery, so when i google for the jQuery Charts , i found this link : http://keith-wood.name/gChartRef.html , i followed this link for my jQuery Chart as i have to display the chart on the mobile device.  Can you please advise whether newer API  (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?csw=1#Configuration_Options) can be used for mobile devices with jquery.  Please share the link if you have any for my problem.

Comment: the option chl: '10%|25%|35%|15%|10%|5%' is showing the percentage outside the slice, i wanted it on the slice. what option can i use for it.

Comment: The Interactive charts will draw on all iOS and Windows Phone devices, and on all Android devices using version 3.2 or higher.  The interactive portion doesn't always work - it depends on whether the browser maps touch events to mouse events.  I don't know of any jQuery plugins that work with the most recent version of the API (there is one that use some deprecated chart packages, but I wouldn't recommend using it), but you don't need to a plugin to use the Visualization API and jQuery together.

Comment: For the pie slice labels, to the best of my knowledge, there is no option to move the labels inside the slices in the Image Chart API.